# dygraph y2 axis was never shown

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am build a service based list (php and js/jquery) with dygraphs. I need to show always both y-Scala. At the first hand is to show different values in the same diagram, on the other hand I need the exact same length of the widget. But the y2 Scala was never shown. Does anybody know which restriction makes my configuration useless?

However, I configure the series, with or without different mapping to the one or other Scala, or toggle it. I checked out that the legend is not cut the dygraph canvas.

````
{
  axes: {
  ​​​  x: {
​​​​      axisLabelWidth: 30,
​​​​      dateWindow: ["2022-02-15T03:57:01.473Z", "2022-02-15T12:57:01.473Z"],
​​​​​      drawAxis: true,
​​​​      pixelsPerLabel: 100
​​​    },
    y: {
​​​​      axisLabelWidth: 40,
​​​​      drawAxis: true,
​​​​      gridLinePattern: [2, 2],
​​​​​      independentTicks: true,
​​​​      pixelsPerLabel: 50,
​​​​      valueFormatter:options_arr.axes.y.valueFormatter(y),
​​​​​      valueRange: [-1, 3],
​​​​​      visibility: true
    },
​​​​    y2: {
​​​​      axisLabelWidth: 40,
​​​​      drawAxis: true,
​​​​      gridLinePattern: [4, 4],
​​​​​      independentTicks: true,
​​​​      pixelsPerLabel: 50,
​​​​      valueFormatter:options_arr.axes.y2.valueFormatter(y2),
​​​​​      valueRange: [-1, 3],
      visibility: true
    },
    ​​​​colors: ["#a1467e", "#000000", "#ff972f", "#ff0000", "#0000c0"],
​​​    connectSeparatedPoints: true,
​​    customBars: true,
​​    disableZoom: true,
​​    height: 300,
​​    labels: ["Time", "B", "Q", "R"],
    labelsDiv: div#archive-legend-7.dygraph-legend,
​​    labelsKMB: true,
​​    labelsSeparateLines: true,
​​    labelsShowZeroValues: true,
​​    legend: "always",
​​    legendFormatter:options_arr.legendFormatter(aData),
​​​    plugins: [ canvas_: canvas, direction_: "both" ],
​​​​    relative: false,
​​    series: {
      "B": {
        axis: "y"
​​​​      },
      "Q": {
​​​​        axis: "y"
      },
      ​​​​"R": {
​​​​        axis: "y"
      }
​​​​    },
    stepPlot: true,
​​    strokeWidth: 2,
​​    title: "B2B",
​​    width: 1200,
​​    xlabel: "Time",
​​    y2label: "SW",
​​    ylabel: "Feedback"
 }
​​​```

If anybody has a clue.
````

Answer (score 0):

From your code example, all your three series (B, Q and R) are assigned to the y axis (`axis = "y"`). You need at least one of the series to be assigned to the second y axis.

For example,

```js
    series: {
      "B": {
        axis: "y"
​​​​      },
      "Q": {
​​​​        axis: "y2"
      },
      ​​​​"R": {
​​​​        axis: "y"
      }
​​​​    }
```

will show series `Q` on the second y axis.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I rewrite a loop to balance the mapping to both scales, so that every y-scale has a series bound, but I see that sometime the y2 scale was drawn and sometimes not. I summarize that. If one or two series is given, no y2 axis was drawn. I don't know what I am doing wrong.  I can see the data now and the definitions of the series without any mistakes.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or codepen that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Hay. It needs a little bit preparation, because data has to be dumped in a right way for paste n copy for jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vicky_laux/7urm65zk/68/

Comment: In fact of lesser answers, I changed the data. I am removing all nulls with last known data. Just it shows lot more y2 labels but ignore my option "drawAxis" if only one dataset is given. That's not a good choice. If I set on y2 the series option "drawAxis" to true and the "visibility" to true, then the y2 axis must be drawn. Right know "drawAxis" has no functionality! If there is no data series read, the dygraph must draw both axis if both axes option "drawAxis" are true. PLEASE FIX IT.

Comment: @VictoriaLaux even with your fiddle I cannot reproduce the problem. I see it drawing both Y scales, left and right one.